# Show automatically getSharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, show

*Please help**

I tried to show the SharedPreferences in my app, but when i open the app the data delete, and i puts button to show again.
I have a button to save data and other to show data, i tried to delate the button to "Show data" and is displayed automatically

Here is the Code

```
public void savePreference(View view)
    {
        SharedPreferences myPreference = getSharedPreferences("MyDate",Context.MODE_ENABLE_WRITE_AHEAD_LOGGING);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPreference.edit();


        EditText editNombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editnombre);
        EditText editApellido = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editapellido);
        EditText editCorreo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editcorreo);
        EditText editnick = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editnick);

        String nombre = editNombre.getText().toString();
        String apellido = editApellido.getText().toString();
        String correo = editCorreo.getText().toString();
        String nickname = editnick.getText().toString();

        editor.putString("nombre",nombre);
        editor.putString("apellido",apellido);
        editor.putString("correo",correo);
        editor.putString("nickname",nickname);

        editor.apply();

        Toast.makeText(edit_profile_activity.this,"Se han agregado datos correctamente",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    public void showPreference (View view)

    {
        SharedPreferences showmypreference = getSharedPreferences("MyDate",Context.MODE_ENABLE_WRITE_AHEAD_LOGGING);

        String nombre = showmypreference.getString("nombre","No existe");
        String apellido = showmypreference.getString("apellido","No existe");
        String correo = showmypreference.getString("correo","No existe");
        String nickname = showmypreference.getString("nickname","No existe");


        TextView nametext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nametext);
        TextView nick = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nickname);
        TextView email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editcorreo);

        String preferencia = (nombre + apellido);
        String shownick = (nickname);
        String showemail =(correo);


        nametext.setText(preferencia);
        nick.setText(shownick);
        email.setText(showemail);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an app with your code and created a layout with the implied EditText and TextView objects on it.  Your code appears to be doing exactly what you told it to do.  When the preferences are saved, the data is read from the 4 EditTexts and saved in the MyDate preferences file.  When the preferences are restored, the data is written to 2 TextViews (nametext and nickname) and to one of the EditTexts (editcorreo).  The other EditTexts will either be restored to their current content by the default onRestoreInstanceState, or will be initialized to whatever the layout or onCreate put in them in initialization.

If you are trying to restore the data to the EditText views as they were when your application exits, then your showPreference method should get references to the EditText views and call the setText method on each one.

```
 EditText editNombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editnombre);
    EditText editApellido = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editapellido);
    EditText editCorreo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editcorreo);
    EditText editnick = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editnick);

    editNombre.setText(nombre);
    editApellido.setText(apellido);
    editCorreo.setText(correo);
    editnick.setText(nickname);
```

Also you are passing a View to each of these methods but not using the parameter in either method.  Unless you have a good reason to leave it, I would recommend deleting the View view parameter.

Comment: The method is probably connected to a click in his xml ... That's why the view arg

Comment: Good point, I usually declare my own click listeners and forget about the XML variety.